# wordpress function.php not load css stylesheet

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I've tried for hours to make wp_enqueue_style running when load in head part.

this is my code

```
function test_script(){

//Add Bootstrap Style
wp_enqueue_style('muarif-bootstrap',get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/css/bootstrap.css');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','test_script');
```

But when i running my website, it's not load properly.

Here is my generated head

```
<head>
     <title>Muarif Gustiar | Web Developer - User Experience - Digital Marketing</title>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="description" content="">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
```

What wrong with my code? i follow the instruction to enqueue [here](http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/06/how-to-enqueue-a-custom-stylesheet-via-functions-php-in-wordpress).
Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure that `get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/css/bootstrap.css'` points to the right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this ago

```
function test_script(){

wp_register_style("bootstrapcss", get_template_directory_uri() . "/inc/css/bootstrap.css");

wp_enqueue_style('bootstrapcss'); 

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','test_script');
```

Comment: change get_template_directory_uri() with get_stylesheet_directory_uri() and u should be good